# Lazy<T> .Subsequent threads to initialize if one thread fails

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, lazy-loading

I am using `Lazy<T>` with `LazyThreadSafetyMode` as `ExecutionAndPublication` and using an initialization method.

What I would like to achieve is  if initialization fails on one thread ,only then the next thread should try and initialize it again. I dont want all threads to race for initialization (as in   Publication only mode) or the exception to be cached and thrown again for all threads (as in ExecutionAndPublication mode).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: With the built in `Lazy<T>` I don't think you can, you will likely need to make your own implementation. In implementing your own we need a few pieces of information. What happens to the first thread that did fail, does it get a exception or does it get the result from the 2nd thread? Also, if all threads fail do you only raise the last exception or do you want a AgragateException containing all of the previous errors?

Comment: Why bother let the first thread fail? Why not just let it try again. You want to first thread to go home alone with only an exception? The first thread is also the one in the best position to retry, no cross thread signaling to tell it to start trying.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain :I would prefer each thread throw the exception back.I need a way to let the threads  try initializing until anyone succeeds. Since it is not possible i may have to contend with Publicationonly mode

Comment: It is possible, it will just take a little work to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286(v=vs.110).aspx)

> As noted in the previous section, Lazy objects created by
>   specifying LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly treat exceptions
>   differently. With PublicationOnly, multiple threads can compete to
>   initialize the Lazy instance. In this case, exceptions are not
>   cached, and attempts to access the Value property can continue until
>   initialization is successful.